Uniswap V2 Quoting using reserves - getamountout methods
I have been having abit of issue with quoting on uniswap v2 based exchanges. I am extracting the reserves and using the formula. - univ2_formula = lambda amount_in, in_lq, out_lq: (out_lqamount_in0.997)/(in_lq+amount_in*0.997) In theory this should work as it is the same function as getamountout on the router. It is giving me the same results but it is not an accurate quote.
There is also quote on the router which just doesnt consider the 0.3% fee. Which is quote_formula = lambda amount_in, in_lq, out_lq: (amount_in*out_lq)/in_lq
When I quote using the actual uniswap v2 website, it is the same as the univ2_formula but it of course has the protocol fee of 0.25% for using the interface on the website. It is giving the same price just the difference of the 0.25%...
So I am not too sure how to actually quote on uniswap v2 as what I am doing seems to be correct but i am getting different results even when i execute the trade. The reserve prices which I have are correct. No other trades are happening between the times I am getting the reserves.
Sidenote, when quoting with uniswapv3 protocols it is accurate using an onchain quoting contract which I deployed… Anythoughts?

Ignoring the UI, are you saying you are getting the same result with your lambda function as calling getAmountOut at the router contract and yet that isn't the same as the price you pay for that exact size when swapping through the v2 router? Would need to see the reserves and exact amounts, the transactions in block, to verify because the getAmount calculations should give accurate results.. Or is this purely a UI based discrepancy?

@Maka That is correct, the lambda, getamountout, AND the uniswap website (minus the 0.25% fee) are all giving the exact same results when called at the same time.
I am creating an arbitrage system, and i need the accuracy of the quotes but there is a discrepancy when i actually execute them based on the result from the quote
